# Repeated Random Number Selection Until No Collisions - Number of Repetitions

Tags: probability, collision-detection

I have a problem that has to do with my research that troubles me for a while and I could not find a solution either by myself or online.

Suppose you have $n$ people in one room. Everyone picks a number. You find out the number of people that have the same number in any way (either all have the same number or some one number and some another and so on) and you keep them in the room and remove everyone else. You do this until no people are left in the room. What is the average times you need to do this with respect to $n$.

Thans in advance for taking the time to answer!

Edit:
The random numbers picked are uniform between $0$ and $N$ ($N$ unrelated to $n$)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please could you clarify a few points (by editing your question)? 1) Are numbers chosen at random or are some numbers more likely than others? 2) Is there an upper limit on the number allowed. If not, then there are an infinite number of possible numbers, and this process will never end. It's also useful to people answering if you share your initial thoughts on the problem - that way we can see what level you are at and answer accordingly.

Comment: In particular, when there are $k$ people in the room, does each one pick a number between $1$ and $k$, perhaps?

Comment: I edited the answer to add the clarifications needed. Thanks!

Comment: @user166281, just to be clear, each person chooses a random *integer* between $0$ and $N$, right?  (If so, why not limit it to integers between $1$ and $N$, so that the probabilities have an $N$ in the denominator, instead of $N+1$?)

Comment: @BarryCipra You are correct. $1$ to $N$ makes no difference to the underlying logic and can be used for calculating the probabilities.

Comment: @user166281, actually I'm beginning to think it does make sense to run things from $0$ to $N$.  Doing so means there's a finite expected time to clearance even when $N=1$.  (You need at least two choices in order to have a chance of eliminating people.  Whatever formula you get for expected time should have a factor of $N$ in its denominator.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that when there are $n$ people, everyone picks a number between 1 and $n$, or between $1$ and some fixed integer $N$. If everyone picks a real number wrt some distribution like the inverse exponential, then no two are ever likely to be equal :).

With that assumption, I believe the answer, for $n > 3$, is "infinity". Why? Because as you decrease the number of people, some fraction -- perhaps ~10%? -- of the time, you'll end up with 3 people in the room. When you do, there's a decent probability that two of them will get the same number, and one will get a different number (e.g., 3, 3, 1). When that happens, there's one person left, and even after infinitely many repetitions, that person is never removed. So your "expected value" computation will have a nonzero probability times an infinite value, resulting in an infinite answer.

Comment: I think the OP means you remove people who *don't* share a number with anyone else, in which case you'll never be left with just one person.

Comment: Ah...that makes more sense, and I agree, on closer reading, that this is probably what OP meant.

Comment: Yes I ment what Barry Cipra said. With this can you suggest a solution? Thanks for answering!